# Using Autosuggest in Adf table

Tags: oracle-adf, autosuggest

I'm using Autosuggest for one of my table column.The issue is  when i use keyboard Up arrow or down arrow,instead of mouse for selecting the values,it is not selecting the values in the autosuggest popup but Its making a row selection in the table. I was looking for a work around for this. Do you have any insights or suggestions. environment Adf 11g R2.

Comment: We had the sames issues. Strange behaviour also with the enter and tab key... We removed all autosuggest behavior from our tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it is needed to press F2 for disable cell navigation mode. Then user need to press the up / down / left or right key for select value from the lists

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. Looks like its working when you press F2. Is there any way that we can do it pragmatically. If you have implemented something like that it would great helpful if you can share